# How to transfer a YouTube username to another email?

Tags: youtube

**The question:**

How can I transfer a YouTube username across to my another email so just that email address is associated with the YouTube username?

Or alternatively how can I connect the 2 accounts so that they both use that YouTube username?

**Details:**

I have a username on youtube that is connected to an email address that I don't use much. This is a gmail address.

I would like to use that youtube username with another email address. This is a @mydomain email address that I use with Google Apps.

The email address that I want to use also has a youtube account. But I don't mind getting rid of that youtube username.

I haven't uploaded videos with either of the usernames.

Is there a way I can switch my youtube username across to the email I usually use?

I see there's a 'Close account' option in youtube, but if I use that, the username doesn't become available (I tried it on another account.)

If I go to google.com/settings for the @gmail user, I can't add my @mydomain as an email address because there's already a google account associated with that email.

So I'm looking for a way to transfer the youtube username across to my other email so just that email address is associated with the youtube username. Or to connect the 2 accounts so that they both use that youtube username.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a chance according to the official [help page](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181261):

> ### Transferring my YouTube account
>
> If your current YouTube account is linked to a Google Account, it may be possible to transfer your YouTube account depending on when it
>   was created. Some settings will be available to you and,
>   unfortunately, some may not.
>
> This is an option for users who created their YouTube Account *before*
>   **May 2009** and then linked to a Google Account.
>
> To transfer your YouTube account from an existing Google Account to
>   another existing Google Account, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Sign in to [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/).
> 2. [Unlink your YouTube account](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=183819).
> 3. [Link your YouTube account](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=69964) to the account of your choice.
>
> <sub>The tips provided in the article are only for users who created
>   their YouTube Account before May 2009. These tips will not help users
>   who created their YouTube Account after May 2009.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't work anymore